# SEO tool is telling me title, description and keywords don't exist, but they do. Where is the problem?

Tags: seo

I'm using the following tool to analyse how 'optimal' a site that I'm working on is for search engines:

http://tools.seobook.com/general/spider-test/

I enter the URL for the site - http://ftmsuat.moneymate.com - into the search bar, and it returns a breakdown of the contents of the page.

I'm a little confused by what I see though. According to the results, the page doesn't have a title, description or keywords. But if you check the source of the page, those elements are definitely there.

So I'm wondering now, which is wrong? seobook.com or my page?

Answer (score 1):

I just tested my site out with this tool and I don't have a title or description either. I think they might have some coding issues with their tool. My title and description show up fine in Google.

Check your search engine listing to make sure that Google can find your title and description and if so, don't worry about it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see them!

Have you tried Seobook.com on other sites or other tools on your site?

The [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org) isn't complaining about anything crucial missing that could cause the tool to "bomb out" and the http://www.reactionengine.com/ found your title and description.

On a side note, you could fit a lot more into the title to make use of it.